# How should I be preparing for managing huge amount of data on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Lately, I am designing a MongoDB-based data storage system for data analysis. I wonder are there anything I should be doing to be preparing for a huge amount of data?

Let's say I gonna collect ppl's purchase behavior every time they purchased anything on my website, and I will analyze these data to find out the trending goods monthly.

Should I create several mongod servers for every single month to do this, or is there a better way to do so? I am worrying about querying will slow down when the database contains too much data.

Comment: Your current question isn't [on-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You could perhaps post on a sibling site like DBA StackExchange, but would need to be much more specific to make the question answerable. The typical scaling approach for a production environment would be to start with a replica set deployment (3 nodes) and eventually scale horizontally using [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/).

Comment: Suitable server resources really depend on your use case requirements (required read/write throughput and latency, working set, ...), budget, and comfort level in setting up, securing, and managing your own infrastructure. There are managed database services that can remove a lot of the operational challenges, but those will also have an associated cost for working with huge amounts of data. I suggest doing some research into MongoDB capacity planning and asking more specific questions on DBA StackExchange based on your requirements.